# how to bind the new values to array variable from one component to another component along with existing data's in first component

Tags: angularjs, angular

i has two components comp1 & comp2

comp1 has one array variable . i created constructor in comp2 for comp1 to access comp1 functions
it is workiing correctly and the values are binding in same array variable which i binds.

i need to bind the value from comp2 along with existing datas in the array variable in comp1

Array variable in comp1 has some values already.

but my problem is when i binding the value from comp2 for the same variable the values are maintaing
seperately not with existing datas in that array variable

how to bind the new values to comp1 variable along with existing datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may directly assign data into `comp1`. Like this.

```
array1 = values;
```

Instead of that, do this way

```
array1.push(values);
```

It will add values in existing array.

And make sure you are passig data in correct way.

[Child to Parent: Sharing Data via ViewChild](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Shared Service.

1) create data.service.ts (simple service)

2) in this service define variable as BehaviorSubject

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

3) add this service as provider in module that is common for two components  (app.module.ts)

4) now you can set sared service variable in components like

```
this.service.changeMessage(newData);
```

and you can subsribe to currentMessage value to get value, like

```
 this.service.currentMessage.subscribe(serviceValue => this.componentMessage = serviceValue );
```

Variable value from service will be the same for all components.